# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I need someone help -

I found this error many times, I am also try with many types but nothing work.

this is my API link --

```
http://103.137.75.74:82/new_connection/?search=test
```

This is my controller ---

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ConnectionController extends GetxController   {
  final _dio = Dio();
  final     connectionList =  [].obs;

  getconnectionList() async {
    try {
      final res = await _dio
          .get('http://support.nbox.live:82/new_connection/?search=test');

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print('-------------------------');
        print('Api data length : ${res.data.length}');
        print('-------------------------');
        print('Get data length : ${connectionList.length}');
        print('-------------------------');

        connectionList.addAll(res.data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I need someone's help. Any senior developer helps me, please.

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question and point to where in your code the error are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

`final     connectionList =  [].obs;`

to this

`final RxList<Map<String, dynamic>> connectionList = [].obs;`

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are looking the solution to this problem, this one works.

##### Precise the datatype that your list contains like so:

```
final RxList<Map<String, dynamic>> connectionList = []<Map<String, dynamic>>.obs;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking the solution to this problem,
This working in my project

RxList<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> items = <Map<dynamic, dynamic>>[].obs;